# Too many graphical interfaces?

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies

Ive installed kde, unity8 and gnome and now I have missing dependencies. Can anyone help me?

```
sudo apt-get -f install

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and others wont work.

for example:

```
sudo apt-get purge kubuntu-desktop
```

puts out:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is currently in beta, and thus questions about it are off-topic here.

Comment: o ok thx, will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge kde-telepathy-minimal kubuntu-desktop 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If that doesn't work, run the following command and then post the errors so that we can proceed:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```